# What to use instead of transistors

Tags: power-supply, transistors, high-voltage

Hi guys I have a problem...

I can’t seem to find a transistor powerful enough to take 10000v, what would I use instead?
Or if you know of a transistor that would take 1A and 10000V please redirect me so I can buy for my usage.

I am looking to build a solenoid engine (reciprocating electric engine) and I am quite new to this.

I am looking for a max power output of 10000W in the engine, that’s 1A X 10000V (stupid power basically) and I can’t find a transistor that won’t break from this input power.
This would be approximately 15Hp
I am looking for an alternative for the transistor in the power supply.

I am doing research into high voltage low amperage setups as I want this to be as energy efficient as possible, using 1A and a 10Ah battery this setup would last for 10Hrs, if I could figure out how to do it right  I want it to last as long as possible so this low an amperage is necessary in my mind.

I don’t want to be using a higher amperage just a high voltage to get the power in the system and Tesla strength in the solenoids electromagnetic fields so the higher voltage and lower amperage is necessary for an efficient long lasting engine.

I am attempting to use a Multiplier Circuit which is designed for AC only, so no DC here I’m afraid Edison, is this even possible?

I want 15Hp max so 10000W overall max power in the system.
High voltage 10000V.
Lower amperage 1A.

I have the engine designed and ready to be built but the power supply system obviously still needs some work and I would rather like a solution to my problem.

I would like to use it in an Electric Skateboard for getting around on an long lasting EV, for that I need to use a low amperage and a high voltage.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can do this?

Many Thanks & Kind Regards

Comment: An electric skateboard with 10 kW motor sounds suicidal.

Comment: You choose a device based on what it has to do (and cope with) in the target circuit. You have not shown a schematic hence this is unanswerable.

Comment: where do the 10kV come from?

Comment: "*using 1A and a 10Ah battery this setup would last for 10Hrs*". It likely wont last 10hrs. The battery wont provide 10000V, so in the process of stepping up, significantly more current is likely to be drawn from the battery.

Comment: How big is a 10,000 V, 10 Ah battery? Where can you get a 10,000 V motor?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. I'm afraid this is both ambitious and impractical in equal amounts, as you've gathered. You can edit your question and greatly improve it, detailing at length your background, situation, problem you're trying to solve and your findings and research. Otherwise, it's likely to be closed, though you can delete it yourself to avoid any downvotes reducing your reputation. Again, welcome.

Comment: what you look for seems too far away from the standards. But If you really want to cut the 10kV power line, a transistor doesn't work.

Comment: 500V 20A  or even 200V 50A will be no less efficient with good design AND you can actually get the bits to do it.

Comment: If you really wanna switch 10,000V, no transistor will do it.  You'd have to go old school and source a specialty vacuum tube.

Answer (score 4):

Have you heard the expression "cut your coat according to your cloth"?

10kV transistors don't appear to exist, no. 1kV seems to be just about feasible with present technology and you can buy bipolar and IGBT transistors with that rating. They need appropriate cooling and sharp switching times to avoid overheating.

> using 1A and a 10Ah battery this setup would last for 10Hrs,

Your next problem is getting a 10kV or even 1kV battery; you could put three thousand standard 18650 cells in series, which is about half a Tesla battery pack, but that's definitely not going to fit on a skateboard. The same set of compromises for voltage vs current have led Tesla to use 375V as their pack voltage.

Your third problem is that putting 10kW into a skateboard wheel is just going to spin it. The normal range of power for these things seems to be below 1kW, which is still a lot.

(I strongly suggest building something in the 100W range first to get the control systems right; that's still enough to have the interesting problems of power electronics, while keeping the potential fires to a manageable size)

Comment: [4700V](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_mosfets/littelfuse_discrete_mosfets_n-channel_standard_ixtl2n470_datasheet.pdf.pdf) supposed to be available late this year.